# What is the max value that Math.random can produce?

Tags: javascript, floating-point, precision

While using `Math.random` of javascript, I came across a interesting question.

According to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random), it produces a "pseudo-random number in the range 0 to less than 1", but what is the biggest number, less than 1 it can produce?

I made this silly code to try getting the highest value

```
maxIteration = 1000000000
value = 0
count = 0
while(value < 1 && count++ < maxIteration) {
    let newValue = Math.random()
    value = value < newValue ? newValue : value
}
console.log('value', value)
console.log('count', count)
```

The highest I could get is `0.9999999989486876`, but is it the highest?

Comment: Probably `1 - 2**-53` which displays as 0.9999999999999999? Maybe someone who knows JS floating point math better can give a proper answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the [docs for numbers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) to understand the float point details.

TLDR: Number type is a double-precision 64-bit binary format IEEE 754 value. A Number only keeps about 17 decimal places of precision; arithmetic is subject to rounding.

```js
var minValue = Number.MIN_VALUE; // 5e-324
// (1 - minValue) == 1

var maxRandom = 1 - 10e-17; // ~= as 1 - (2e-53)

document.body.innerHTML = 'Number.MIN_VALUE = '+ minValue + '<br>maxRandom = ' + maxRandom;
```

Comment: `Number.MIN_VALUE` isn't relevant here, since `Math.random` is inclusive on the low end (it can produce `0.0` in theory). Possibly helpful in other contexts though.

Comment: I just added it in case someone considers (1 - MIN_VALUE) to be the actual answer, but it rounds up to one. I think I should have made that more clear.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the max value that `Math.random` can produce?

The documentation fails to state that, both the Mozilla documentation you point to and the [ECMAScript Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf) (2020 version at time of writing).

The maximum value less than 1 that the `Number` type can represent is 1−2<sup>−53</sup>. (This value occurs when all 53 bits of the significand are ones and the exponent is −1, giving the value +1.111…111<sub>2</sub>•2<sup>−1</sup> = 1−2<sup>−53</sup>.) Ideally, that would be the maximum value `Math.random` returns, but the documentation does not say so.